# activejdbc include parent recursively

Tags: activejdbc

I'm work with activejdbc and:

I have 3 Models: City belongs to State belongs to Country, ok? I do this:

Paginator p = new Paginator(City.class, count, filters).orderBy(orderParams);
LazyList page = p.getPage(pag).include(State.class);

This, loads cities with their states (i do page.toMaps()),

Now I want to load the country also

It's possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `include()` method goes on dependencies only one level up or down. This means that if you are starting at the level of CIty, you can only get a state. If you want to get both, you can start at the level of State like this:

```
Paginator p = new Paginator(State.class, count, filters) 
                                       .orderBy(orderParams); 
LazyList page = p.getPage(pag).include(City.class, Country.class);
```

Not sure of this will work for you though. Here is an example without the Paginator: 
http://javalite.io/lazy_and_eager#eager-simultaneous-loading-of-parents-and-children

Comment: can anyone suggest any simple orm for java with recursive relation loading?

Comment: What if there's a table `continents` and I want to eager load its record, too?

Comment: it is hard to answer your question without understanding your data model. File a new issue here as a question and  supply more detail: https://github.com/javalite/javalite/issues